# Set an xslt variable with an email

Tags: xslt-1.0, biztalk, biztalk-2013

In a BizTalk mapper, I had to set a default e-mail in output field when a specific input field is null or empty.

So I set an XSLT variable with the email but when the condition is good no node is created in the output.

Here is my code:

```
<xsl:template name="GetEmail">
  <xsl:param name="number" />
  <xsl:param name="Email" />
  <xsl:variable name="defaultmail">noreply&#64;domain.fr</xsl:variable>

  <xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name()='Employee']">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="*[local-name()='Username' and text() = $number] and $Email != ''">
        <xsl:element name="email">      
          <xsl:value-of select="string(*[local-name()='Email'])" />
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="*[local-name()='Username' and text() = $number] and $Email = ''">
        <xsl:element name="email">      
          <xsl:value-of select="$defaultmail" />
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>      
</xsl:template>
```

Here is my Input file:

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/aggschema">
    <InputMessagePart_0>
        <Get>
            <Employee>
                <Username>008441</Username>
                <Email />
            </Employee>
            <Employee>
                <Username>014095</Username>
                <Email>email2@domain.fr</Email>
            </Employee>
            <Employee>
                <Username>011812</Username>
                <Email>email3@domain.fr</Email>
            </Employee>
        </Get>
    </InputMessagePart_0>
    <InputMessagePart_1>
        <ns1:EmployeeResponse xmlns:ns1="http://Employee">
            <ns1:Header /> 
            <ns1:Return>
                <ns1:Employee>
                    <ns1:Number>008441</ns1:Number>
                </ns1:Employee>
            </ns1:Return>
        </ns1:EmployeeResponse>
    </InputMessagePart_1>
</ns0:Root>
```

And here is the output:

```
<Employee>
  <username>123456789</username> 
  <firstname>Firstname</firstname> 
  <lastname>Lastname</lastname>
  <birthdate>dd/MM/yyyy</birthdate>
<email />
</Employee>
```

And what it should be:

```
<Employee>
  <username>123456789</username> 
  <firstname>Firstname</firstname> 
  <lastname>Lastname</lastname>
  <email>noreply@domain.fr</email>
  <birthdate>dd/MM/yyyy</birthdate>
</Employee>
```

I have 2 input files, one is provided by my customer and the other is provided by our DB.
The first file from customer contains a list of employees.
The second file from our DB contains only one employee identified with the *Username* in the first file. There is a loop so for each employee in the first file we get the employee datas related to *Username*. We need two datas in our DB related to each employee to calculate 2 fields in output file.
The output must contains all datas from the first one and the 2 calculated fields.
If the email field is not provided (empty or null) in the first file (from my customer), BizTalk mapper take the email of the next employee with an non empty email field.
So in my example, the output will be:

```
<Employee>
  <username>008441</username> 
  <firstname>Firstname</firstname> 
  <lastname>Lastname</lastname>
  <email>email2@domain.fr</email>
  <birthdate>dd/MM/yyyy</birthdate>
</Employee>
```

instead of :

```
<Employee>
  <username>008441</username> 
  <firstname>Firstname</firstname> 
  <lastname>Lastname</lastname>
  <email>noreply@domain.fr</email>
  <birthdate>dd/MM/yyyy</birthdate>
</Employee>
```

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I added example input file

Comment: I take it you are trying to get the Email from the Get, and match it to the username from the Return, which I assume would have the other details such as firstname, lastname and birthdate, that seem to be missing from your example input.  If I use your XSLT and have the links coming from the GET it works, if I have split across the two it doesn't.  I think you are going to have to give us a sample map and schemas, and explain what you are trying to do in more detail.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I updated my post. For the mapping, I connected the filed _Number_ from _InputMessagePart_1_ to output corresponding fields (in my case _email_ field) via a scripting functoïd where I put my XSLT code. While I didn't had to put a default value if input _Email_ field (from  _InputMessagePart_0)_ is empty, it was working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should NOT try to link from both InputMessagePart_0 and InputMessagePart_1, that just confuses the looping, and you are already creating the loop inside the XSLT for InputMessagePart_0 with your `for-each-select`.  Just link the Number from InputMessagePart_1 and use the following XSLT.  Also select the Email from the node, and not pass it in as a variable.

```
<xsl:template name="GetEmail">
  <xsl:param name="number" />
  <xsl:variable name="defaultmail">noreply&#64;domain.fr</xsl:variable>

  <xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name()='Employee']">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="*[local-name()='Username' and text() = $number]">
       <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="*[local-name()='Email' and text() != '']">
           <xsl:element name="email">
            <xsl:value-of select="string(*[local-name()='Email'])" />
           </xsl:element>
         </xsl:when>
           <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:element name="email">      
             <xsl:value-of select="$defaultmail" />
           </xsl:element>
         </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
     </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>      
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code to:

```
    <xsl:template name="GetEmail">
  <xsl:param name="number" />
  <xsl:param name="Email" />
  <xsl:variable name="defaultmail">
      <xsl:value-of select='noreply@domain.fr'/>
   </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name()='Employee']">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="[local-name()='Username' and text() = $number]  and string-length($Email) &gt;0">
        <xsl:element name="email">      
          <xsl:value-of select="string(*[local-name()='Email'])" />
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="*[local-name()='Username' and text() = $number] and string-length($Email) &eq;0">
        <xsl:element name="email">      
          <xsl:value-of select="$defaultmail" />
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>      
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: It doesn't works. the '&eq;' is not recognize by BizTalk mapper.

Comment: change it with = directly

Comment: I did it and doesn't work either. The email field is missing in the output.

Comment: can you share how you call GetEmail template

Comment: I call it inside a BizTalk mapper with a functoid.